# Проблема с VK (ВКонтакте) API photos.search

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Использую API ВКонтакте на протяжении года. Мое приложение отображает фото пользователей ВК на карте по всему миру. В основном используется метод [photos.search](https://vk.com/dev/photos.search). В последние дни объем данных, возвращаемых данным методом, упал приблизительно на 50% по сравнению с прошлыми месяцами. В некоторых местах количество фотографий упало с нескольких сотен в день до нескольких десятков. Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобной проблемой? Может в работе API произошли какие-то изменения? В официальной документации ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, с какими параметрами вы вызываете данный метод? Отличаются ли результаты в консоли от результатов вызова через API? Пробовали ли вы определить, какие именно фотографии не попадают в выдачу?